# AFNetworking PUT and Delete with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, api, http, afnetworking

In looking at the AFNetworking documentation, the Put and Delete methods take in a path and a dictionary of parameters.  I am using Rails as my backend which expects these two types to take the form of Put /object/1.json and Delete /object/1.json.  Should I build up a path string by adding in the Id or do I send a Put or Delete with the Id as one of the params in the Dictionary?

Comment: I'm in a similar boat. I have PUT and GET requests working, but am confused as to how to create the path for a DELETE request with AFNetworking. I'm talking to a postgresql db if thats any comfort.

Comment: I am using Postgres as well.  I tried passing in a dictionary of params but that didn't work.  In the code if I manually set the full path for a delete such as [[APIManager sharedManager] deletePath:@"/v1/object/3.json" parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) then it works as noted in my original.  Thinking I will just need to concat a string together.

Comment: I tried the dictionary of params as well to no avail. I'll try that. It makes sense, I wish the afnetworing documentation went into more detail about the path parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Typically when I do with `PUT` and similar type HTTP requests when using `AFNetworking` is something like this:

```c
// Create an HTTP client with your site's base url
AFHTTPClient *client = [AFHTTPClient clientWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com"]];

// Setup the other parameters you need to pass
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"username" : @"bob", @"password" : @"123456"};

// Create a NSURLRequest using the HTTP client and the path with your parameters
NSURLRequest *request = [client requestWithMethod:@"PUT" path:@"object/1.json" parameters:parameters];

// Create an operation to receive any response from the server
AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
    // Do stuff
} failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
    // Handle error
}];

// Begin the operation
[operation start];
```

If you look in `AFHTTPClient.h` there are examples for how to format your base url and your paths. There's more information on these methods in the [AFNetworking documentation](http://afnetworking.github.com/AFNetworking/Classes/AFHTTPClient.html#//api/name/getPath:parameters:success:failure:)

Comment: Hi Keith. In your "object/1.json" example, it is the "1" that I am wondering about how to handle.  Since that generally refers to the id of a dynamic object I am working with I would not be able to hardcode that.

Comment: Well if you were adding a new item you would just do the path `object` (most likely) otherwise you would have to have the value of the object somewhere when you downloaded it so you could input it's value into the path when you're ready to delete it. For example if you downloaded the objects they should have some sort of unique identifier that you'll get initially.