# AFNetworking and DELETE requests with Rails

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, heroku, afnetworking

I'm putting the finishing touches on my own version of the heroku rails mobile iOS photo sharing app. I have implemented and successfully sent POST and GET requests via HTTP on iOS. Unfortunately, the Heroku tutorial explicitly states it won;t be going into how to write the DELETE request. Here's what I have so far:

```
+ (void)deletePhoto:(NSString *)owner
          image:(NSString *)recordId
          block:(void (^)(Photo *, NSError *))block
{
NSMutableDictionary *mutableParameters = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[mutableParameters setObject:recordId forKey:@"photo[id]"];

NSLog(@"Destroying %@", recordId);
[[CloudGlyphAPIClient sharedClient] deletePath:@"/photo" parameters:mutableParameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id JSON) {
    if (block) {
        NSLog(@"DELETE sussessful");
    }
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    if (block) {
        block(nil, error);
    }
}];
}

+ (void)getPhotos:(NSString *)owner
                 block:(void (^)(NSSet *photos, NSError *error))block
{
NSMutableDictionary *mutableParameters = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[mutableParameters setObject:owner forKey:@"photo[owner]"];

[[CloudGlyphAPIClient sharedClient] getPath:@"/photos" parameters:mutableParameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id JSON) {
    NSMutableSet *mutablePhotos = [NSMutableSet set];
    for (NSDictionary *attributes in [JSON valueForKeyPath:@"photos"]) {
        Photo *photo = [[Photo alloc] initWithAttributes:attributes];
        [mutablePhotos addObject:photo];
    }

    if (block) {
        block([NSSet setWithSet:mutablePhotos], nil);
    }
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    if (block) {
        block(nil, error);
    }
}];
```

}

I've based the DELETE request off of the GET request, except in this case we are looking for a particular image user a certain owner. I get an error that the routes file doesn't contain a path for DELETE /photos... i added the destroy method to the rails app and raked the routes.rb file.

I feel like this is a rails GOTCHA somewhere.. thanks for your help ^_^

**TL;DR** trying to write DELETE request for a rails app with AFNetworking

Comment: it looks like the deletePath is supposed to be the url of the resource attempting to be deleted - wonder how thats formed? Also, the rails app is using Paperclip, but I think in the destroy method i merely need to say '@photo'.image.destroy. photo being the ActiveRecord, and image being the attachment field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In AFNetworking, the DELETE path is a url path like this: photos/18.json is the record marked for removal. Found the answer over here: 
[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12449268/afnetworking-put-and-delete-with-rails)

Effectively, one can concat together a string to the url of the ActiveREcord in a table.